# Writing an integration test for aspect functionality in Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-aop, aspect

I was wondering what I am doing wrong when testing my aspect functionality. The aspect is working in production (passed testing by QA), but I am trying to get my integration unit test to pass. Here is my code:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

@Pointcut("execution(* com.example.dao.UsersDao(..)) && args(.., restrictions)")
protected void allUsersPointcut(List<String> restrictions) {

}

@Around("allUsersPointcut(restrictions)")
public Object applyUserRestrictions(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, List<String> restrictions) throws Throwable {

  String restrict = "Jack";
  restrictions.add(restrict);

  return pjp.proceed();
}
```

My DAO method just returns a list of all users, but when the aspect is used it restricts what users are shown.

```
@Repository
UsersDaoImpl implements UsersDao {
  ...
}
```

And my UsersService:

```
@Service
public class UsersService implements UsersService {
  @Autowired
  protected UsersDAO usersDAO;

  ...

  @Transactional(readOnly=true)
  public List<String> findUsers(List<String> restrictions) {
    return this.usersDAO.findUsers(restrictions);
  }
}
```

In my unit test I am doing the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class UserTest {

@Autowired
UsersService usersService;

@Test
public void testAspect() {

  List<String> restrictions = null;
  List<String> users = this.usersService.findUsers(restrictions);
  Assert.notNull(users);
}
```

I've also added the xml confguration:

```
context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.aspect" />
```

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `usersDao` declared/initialised in your test class?

Comment: ... and what does your test failure look like?  What is `Assert?` (`org.junit.Assert` doesn't have a `notNull()` method)

Comment: @slim Apologies, I have edited the class now to include where I have added the declaration of `usersDao`. `org.springframework.util.Assert` has a `notNull()` method

Comment: OK, I suggest not using that `Assert` in your tests. Its Javadoc says "Mainly for internal use within the framework". `import static org.junit.Assert.*` and use `assertNotNull(...)` or `assertThat()` -- it's more familiar to people in general.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see of your test, it ought to work - so you have some tweaking to do regarding classpath scanning, ensuring the test is using the expected configuration etc.

I recommend temporarily adding:

```
 @Autowired
 ApplicationContext context;

 @Before
 public void dumpBeans() {
      System.out.println(context.getBeansOfType(UsersDao.class));
 }
```

Or, more simply, `System.out.println(usersDao.getClass())` in the test method.

You could also run your test in a debugger - add a breakpoint in your test class, and check what class `usersDao` is at runtime.

Comment: Hi @slim, I have edited my code above in the test to use the service class (other integration tests in our application only use these) so I'm not sure if that changes anything but I have still not been able to get it working.